# JavaScript cookies not saving?

Tags: javascript, cookies

So i'm loading my cookies onload, but when I originally create a cookie, it's not saving in Chrome. It works fine in Safari though until I quit and relaunch. Here's my JS relevent to the cookies:

```
console.log("Raw Cookie: "+document.cookie)
var serverIP = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)serverIpCookie\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");
var ipUI = false
console.log("Cookie: "+serverIP)

function checkCookie(){
    if (serverIP == ''){
        document.getElementById("serverInfoID").style.display='block';
    }else if (!(serverIP == '')){
        document.getElementById("serverInfoID").style.display='none';
        updateDevice(9999);
    };
};

function getServerInfo(){
    if (!(document.getElementById('usip').value == '')){
        var now = new Date();
        now.setMonth( now.getMonth() + 1)
        if (serverIP == ''){
            serverIP = "ws://"+document.getElementById('usip').value+":8000";
            document.cookie = "serverIpCookie=" + serverIP + ";";
            document.cookie = "expires=" + now.toUTCString() + ";"
        }else{
            serverIP = "ws://"+document.getElementById('usip').value+":8000";
            document.cookie = "serverIpCookie=" + serverIP + ";";
            document.cookie = "expires=" + now.toUTCString() + ";"
        }
        document.getElementById('usipButton').style.background="#f39c12";
        updateDevice(9999, true);

    };
};
```